# FileFilter for JFileChooser doesn't work

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser, filefilter

Below is my code to open a `JFileChooser` on the click of a button. I have created a filter to allow the selection of only .jpg files, but my code doesn't work as expected. All types of files are shown in `JFileChooser` diaog box. Part of code:

```
MyFileFilter filter;

fPhoto=new JFileChooser();
fPhoto.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);        
fPhoto.setFileFilter(filter);
```

MyFileFilter class:

```
public class MyFileFilter extends javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter{

    public boolean accept(File f){

    return f.isDirectory()||(f.isFile()&&f.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".jpg"));
    }

    public String getDescription(){

    return ".jpg files";
    }
}
```

Comment: It'd be far faster, and more educational, to fire up a debugger, set a breakpoint or two, and step through the code to see what you've done wrong.  Be assumed that this class works fine when implemented properly.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't initialize `filter` variable. I'm not sure but this may be the reason.

Comment: [The First Rule of Programming: It's Always Your Fault](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/03/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault.html) - your `filter` is `null`

Comment: A very silly mistake :D! Thanks khachik!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to instantiate your `filter`. Having a `null` `FileFilter` will result in no file types being filtered out:

```
MyFileFilter filter = new MyFileFilter();
```

Comment: No problem, Happy Holidays! :)

Answer (score 3):

If you want browse specified files, Take a look at this code

```
 try
        {
        JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
        fc.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
        fc.setFileFilter(new FileFilter() {

            @Override
            public boolean accept(File file) {
               return (file.isDirectory()||file.getName().endsWith(".JPG")||file.getName().endsWith(".jpg"));
            }

            @Override
            public String getDescription() {
                return "Multi-Video Files";
            }
        });
        File file;
        if(JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION==fc.showDialog(null, "Select Files"))   
        {
           File file = fc.getSelectedFile();  //HERE YOU WILL GET THE SELECTED FILE 
        }
        }catch(Exception e){System.out.println("error");
        }
```

If you want to browse only directories then

```
JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
     File file;
     fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);

     if(JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION==fc.showDialog(null, "Select"))   
     {
      File file = fc.getSelectedFile();  //HERE YOU WILL GET THE SELECTED DIRECTORY PATH 
     }
```